# "Numerical-analysis" needs some love!

Tags: discussion, tags

#### **Tag:** [numerical-analysis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis)

#### **[Questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis) asked till date**: 18

#### **The problem:**

Evident misuse in a variety of problems from sig figs to kinetics to electrochem, simply because there is **no tag wiki for this tag till date.**

#### **Recommended action:**

**Delete the tag and remove it from all the current questions,** especially since there were no usage guidelines regarding it, it is almost certain that this tag has been misused.

---

**Requesting confirmation to hit the "nuke" button in 3,2,1...!**

Comment: I will check that out later, but in general I agree with that proposal.

Comment: I am surprised no one mentioned the irony between the question title and the question body :P

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Did you check it out? Besides, I also realized that the [tagwiki](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tags/analytical-chemistry/info) for [tag:analytical-chemistry] includes numeric-analysis inside it. So, that's another reason to burn [tag:numerical-analysis]

Comment: no, sorry, no time. Maybe after my absence...